# Get formatted text from RichTextBox control

Tags: asp.net, richtextbox

I'm using a [RichTextBox](http://www.freetextbox.com/) control.  I need to get the formatted text(not the plain text) from the code behind.  How can I do this?

I'm using the control in a email template

Comment: Freetextbox should have a text or content property which will rerturn you html format text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `freeTextBox.Text`. According to documentation, the [Text](http://www.freetextbox.com/docs/ftb3/html/P_FreeTextBoxControls_FreeTextBox_Text.htm) property Gets or sets  the HTML which should have the all the formatting.

Comment: yup freeTextBox.Text will definitely serve the purpose

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string s = richTextBox.Rtf;
```

Comment: above controller doesn't have Rtf property

Comment: @chamara: then there should be be `content` property.

Comment: @chamara: now your can try this `Text` or  `HtmlStrippedText`

Comment: i'm getting the following "error.System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client".i think it says page submit doesn't allow html tags.any idea on that? thanks

Comment: i fixed the issue by adding ValidateRequest="false" on my page header.but still the formatted text doesn't appear.